# onConnectCallback not invoking while making WAMP connection using Autobahn-java

Tags: java, android, autobahn

I am using this code (as shown in ExampleClient of Autobahn demo) to connect the client:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    session = new Session(executor);
    session.addOnConnectListener(this);
    session.addOnJoinListener(this);
    session.addOnLeaveListener(this);
    session.addOnDisconnectListener(this);

    // Now create a transport list to try and add transports to it.
    // In our case, we currently only have Netty based WAMP-over-WebSocket.
    List<ITransport> transports = new ArrayList<>();
    transports.add(new NettyTransport("wss://xxxxxxx.com/wss2/", executor));

    // Now provide a list of authentication methods.
    // We only support anonymous auth currently.
    List<IAuthenticator> authenticators = new ArrayList<>();
    authenticators.add(new AnonymousAuth());

    // finally, provide everything to a Client instance and connect
    Client client = new Client(transports, executor);
    client.add(session, mLiveStream.streamName, authenticators);
    client.connect();
```

But the onConnect callback never gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the function name,
change :

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
session = new Session(executor);
session.addOnConnectListener(this);
session.addOnJoinListener(this);
session.addOnLeaveListener(this);
session.addOnDisconnectListener(this);
```

to :

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
session = new Session(executor);
session.addOnConnectListener(this::functionName);
session.addOnJoinListener(this::functionName2);
session.addOnLeaveListener(this::functionName3);
session.addOnDisconnectListener(this::functionName4);
```

refer to the [readme](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-java/blob/master/README.md#connecting-the-dots)